# Add months to a date using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple MVC form with the following elements:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("FechaInicio") %>
```

Which has the start date.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Meses") %>
```

Which has the amount of months I want to add.

I'd like to take the date that has been entered on the first textbox, add the amount of months that have been entered on the second textbox and get that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using whatever date formation you've established, parse the value of `FechaInicio` into `year`, `month` and `day`.  Get the value of `Meses`.

```
// Magical parsing of `FechaInicio` here
var year = 2010, month = 9, day = 14;
// The value of `meses`
var meses_mas = 3;

var future_date = new Date(year, month + meses_mas, day);

console.log(future_date);
```

You'll end up with `Wed Apr 14 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PST)` (timezone may vary).  JavaScript's Date object will handle month overflow for you.

Also, as a side note, `Date` treats months as zero-indexed (0 = January ... 11 = December).

Comment: Actually I just had to add a Number() to do a cast on each var before I added them..

Answer (score 0):

I'd parse the value of the start date into a javascript date object. Then use something like below.

```
var startDate = parseDate();
var monthsToAdd = getMonthsToAdd();

while (startDate.getMonth() + monthsToAdd > 11) {
  startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + 1);
  monthsToAdd - 11;
}

startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() + monthsToAdd);
```

Comment: That loop really isn't necessary.  `Date` will handle month overflow for you automagically.  See my answer.

Comment: gtk, the documentation didn't say that explicitly so I thought I would cover my bases.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var numofMonthtoAdd = 5; //number of month you may want to add

        var beginDate = new Date();
        var month = (parseInt(beginDate.getMonth()) + parseInt(numofMonthtoAdd )) % 12;
        var year = (parseInt(beginDate.getMonth()) + parseInt(numofMonthtoAdd )) / 12;
        beginDate.setMonth(month);
        beginDate.setFullYear(parseInt(beginDate.getFullYear()) + year );
        return beginDate;
```